# Display image with wildcard in src with javascript or angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display multiple images starting with _id value in ng-repeat  in the view like this .

```
 <div ng-repeat="property in properties">
    <img src="uploads/@{{property._id}}.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42"/>
</div>
```

now consider this 
if

> _id = 1

there are multiple images in the uploads like this

> /uploads/

```
1a.jpg
1b.jpg
1zaz.jpg
1io.jpg
```

i want to show all those images against every property,.

Help me for this.

Comment: I mean to show multiple images against an id in angular ng-repeat. all images name starts with id then random string .jpg.

Comment: *"multiple images against an id"* doesn't make much sense as clarification either. Don't make us guess what you are trying to do....give a proper explanation

Comment: The right way is: use ng-src (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder is it clear now?

Comment: @InzmamGujjar: Nice one!

Comment: @T.J. Crowder kindly take back your down vote atleast

Comment: @InzmamGujjar: A) You have no idea whether I voted (either downvoted or vote-to-close). B) What makes you think that *if* I downvoted or voted to close, I didn't retract them when posting "nice one!" as you'd resolved the issues with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now consider this if
>
> ```
> _id = 1
> ```
>
> there are multiple images in the uploads like this
>
> ```
> /uploads/
> 1a.jpg
> 1b.jpg
> 1zaz.jpg
> 1io.jpg
> ```
>
> i want to show all those images against every property

The only way you can do that is if you know in advance that the names have `a`, `b`, `zaz`, and `io` appended to them. You can't use a wildcard to say "repeat this `img` element for any files that happen to exist."

So as part of your build process or similar, you'll need to identify the actual images that exist, and then cover all of them within the `ng-repeat`. The details of how you do that are obviously going to be highly specific to your environment, so we can't give you those specifics.

Comment: but user can upload multiple images against single property so i have to append random string at the end to store them,.,

Comment: @InzmamGujjar: That server-side information just isn't available from browser-hosted JavaScript. You'd have to capture the names when the user uploads them, and then use those captured names when rendering.

Comment: The other possible solution could be to store the name of the images in the database array and then ng-repeat that array ,., but that might reduce the performence ng-repeat within an ng-repeat,., what do you thnk?

Comment: @InzmamGujjar: Doesn't really matter if you have an ng-repeat of, say, two items that each has an ng-repeat of, say, four items, vs just an ng-repeat of eight items. If you can have multiple images aginst the same property, then a nested repeat makes sense.